# scope of Julia variable with if block nested in for loop

Tags: julia

```
for i=1:5
    if(i==1)
        z = i
    end
    println("i = $i, z = $z")
end

i = 1, z = 1
ERROR: UndefVarError: z not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at ./REPL[6]:5 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at ./none:0
```

The behavior of the above script is puzzling to me. Can someone help me understand why the print works when i=1 but fails when i=2.

Comment: have you defined z previous to the z = i statement?  If i does not equal one then z remains undefined when you call it to print.  You have to set a default value for z, or do a conditional check before your print so it does not report z if i does not equal one.

Comment: No, z was not defined outside the if block. **I thought that the definition when i=1 should persist when i>1 as if blocks do not define a local scope**. This seems to be true as the print outside the if block works when i=1. My question is why does it fail when i=2.

Comment: when i equals anything, besides 1, for instance 2, then your z = i does not execute.  when you call your print every time regardless of the value of i, z is only defined for one instance, when i = 1, then z=i.  So for any other value of i, z does not get brought into existence, when you call the print statement z does not exist as a variable on the stack.  So 1) do not print Z if i != 1 or two make two print statements.

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation-1 Search for the text "if blocks are "leaky" ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by @Wookies-Will-Code is correct and here is the reason.

As the Julia manual explains [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#For-Loops-and-Comprehensions-1):

> `for` loops, `while` loops, and [Comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1) have the following behavior: any new variables introduced in their body scopes are freshly allocated for each loop iteration

Which means that at the end each iteration `z` is forgotten.

In order to make sure the value of `z` is persistent across iterations (and also after `for` loop finishes) define `z` before the loop. For example like this:

```
function mytest()
    local z
    for i=1:5
        if i==1
            z = i
        end
        println("i = $i, z = $z")
    end
end
```

and now you have:

```
julia> mytest()
i = 1, z = 1
i = 2, z = 1
i = 3, z = 1
i = 4, z = 1
i = 5, z = 1
```

Observe that the situation is different in global scope. Even if `z` is globally defined it is not reused by default:

```
julia> z = 100
100

julia> for i=1:5
           if i==1
               z = i
           end
           println("i = $i, z = $z")
       end
i = 1, z = 1
ERROR: UndefVarError: z not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at .\REPL[7]:5 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at .\none:0
```

The reason is that Julia treats `z` as local to the for loop, because `z` is assigned to inside the loop. This is a compile time feature check so even if the `if` condition always fails you will get this error:

```
julia> z = 100
100

julia> for i=1:5
           if false
               z = i
           end
           println("i = $i, z = $z")
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: z not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at .\REPL[18]:5 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at .\none:0
```

You have to assign to `z` using `global` keyword to make it work:

```
julia> z = 100
100

julia> for i=1:5
           if i==1
               global z = i
           end
           println("i = $i, z = $z")
       end
i = 1, z = 1
i = 2, z = 1
i = 3, z = 1
i = 4, z = 1
i = 5, z = 1
```

Comment: That's a nice explanation. But I'm not sure that loops are of fundamental importance here. You would get the same behavior inside a function: `function sometimes(i) if i == 1 z = i end; println(z) end`. `sometimes(1)` works, `sometimes(0)` does not. The fact that all possible code paths must assign a value to `z` when `z` is declared in an if block seems to be a "deeper" reason here. I might be wrong though.

Comment: From my experience the special thing about `for` loop is exactly that it is not special. The fact that it behaves exactly like a function or `let` block surprises most people coming from other languages, like Python. This behavior has been made strict only recently in Julia 1.0 release when the distinction between soft and hard local scope was dropped. For instance if the original code used `while` loop not `for` loop and was run under Julia 0.6 then it would work although `while` loop introduced a local scope.

Comment: That is the explanation that I needed. Thanks very much!

Comment: In JupyterLab, the code given above by Bogumił Kamiński works even without the global z statement.

Comment: It works because Jupyter in Julia by default loads https://github.com/stevengj/SoftGlobalScope.jl package. See here https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl#opting-out-of-soft-scope for the instructions how to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use Julia, but here goes.  I am not sure how to send the string that z is not defined, but here 2 different prinln based on the value of i, simplest way to do it, or else you have to check if z is defined, this is simpler.

```
for i=1:5
    if(i==1)
        z = i
        println("i = $i, z = $z")
    else
        println("i = $i","z not defined")
    end
end
```